# show my address in Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dictionary, location

I do use the Google Maps API v2 to get my location on the map. Is it possible to write the correct address in the information of the marker?

I didn't find anything useful in the internet..

Here is my code. Thanks in advance!

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
 GoogleMap map;

  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

   lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

   map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
    .getMap();

  }

  @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   map.clear();

   MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

   mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

   mp.title("my position");

   map.addMarker(mp);

   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16));         
  }

  @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can, for that you need to create custom info window

Answer (score 0):

you want to add extra information on the marker? If i understood correctly then you can add a snipper.

```
LatLng mark = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(longi));
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("MY Position").snippet("Extra info").position(mark));
```